# python find substrings based on a delimiter

Tags: python, regex, string

I am new to Python, so I might be missing something simple.

I am given an example:

```
 string = "The , world , is , a , happy , place "
```

I have to create substrings separated by `,` and print them and process instances separately. 
That means in this example I should be able to print

```
The 
world 
is 
a
happy 
place
```

What approach can I take? I was trying to use the string find functionality, but

```
Str[0: Str.find(",") ]
```

does not help in finding 2nd, 3rd instances.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try using the `split` function.

In your example:

```
string = "The , world , is , a , happy , place "
array = string.split(",")
for word in array:
    print word
```

Your approach failed because you indexed it to yield the string from beginning until the first ",". This could work if you then index it from that first "," to the next "," and iterate across the string that way. Split would work out much better though.

Answer (score 7):

Strings have a `split()` method for this.  It returns a list:

```
>>> string = "The , world , is , a , happy , place "
>>> string.split(' , ')
['The', 'world', 'is', 'a', 'happy', 'place ']
```

As you can see, there is a trailing space on the last string. A nicer way to split this kind of string would be this:

```
>>> [substring.strip() for substring in string.split(',')]
['The', 'world', 'is', 'a', 'happy', 'place']
```

`.strip()` strips whitespace off the ends of a string.

Use a `for` loop to print the words.

Answer (score 4):

Another option:

```
import re

string = "The , world , is , a , happy , place "
match  = re.findall(r'[^\s,]+', string)
for m in match:
    print m
```

Output

```
The
world
is
a
happy
place
```

See a [demo](https://eval.in/48591)

You could also just use `match  = re.findall(r'\w+', string)` and you will get the same output.

Answer (score 2):

Simple thanks to the convenient string methods in Python:

```
print "\n".join(token.strip() for token in string.split(","))
```

Output:

```
The
world
is
a
happy
place
```

By the way, the word `string` is a bad choice for variable name (there is an `string` module in Python).