# How to extract first string between special character from txt file python

Tags: python, string, extract

I have a list of emails and passwords divided by `:` which are stored in `myfile.txt` file in application location path.

Now each email and password are stored in one line for each account.

Now I need python to extract from first line email and then other method to extract the passwords.

**Here is the formatted text:**

```
email01@gmail.com:pass01
email02@gmail.com:pass02
email03@gmail.com:pass03
email04@gmail.com:pass04
```

**MY CODE:**

```
self._emailLoaded = open("./accounts.txt", "r").read().splitlines()
_email = self._emailLoaded ([0])
_password = self._emailLoaded ([1])
```

I need to email gets the first `_email` from first line and next if it is called it pick up the next line and next email; the same for `_password`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python find substrings based on a delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18808707/python-find-substrings-based-on-a-delimiter)

Comment: We have no idea what `_accLoaded` is. Nothing here seems to be dealing with the logic that you are describing.

Comment: @tripleee sorry error _emailLoaded

Comment: It's not a function so it can't be called. The zeroth element would be the first line, not the first column.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I need to extract firt string and your links showed the exactly name like 'word'

Comment: @mkrieger1'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: Python strings have a *split()* function. That will help you a lot. Take a look at the documentation:- https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement a generator that opens the file, reads one line at a time, splits the line and yields the two constituent parts. Something like this:

```
FILENAME = 'myfile.txt'

def parse(filename):
    with open(filename) as data:
        for line in data:
            yield line.rstrip().split(':')

for email, password in parse(FILENAME):
    print(f'{email=} {password=}')
```

**Output:**

```
email='email01@gmail.com' password='pass01'
email='email02@gmail.com' password='pass02'
email='email03@gmail.com' password='pass03'
email='email04@gmail.com' password='pass04'
```

Comment: "parse" is not definedPylance

Comment: @Jane1990 Yes it is. Can you see where it says *def parse....*

Comment: I dont have 'filename' I have self._emailLoaded and it doesnt work at all also you gave another similar FILENAME which is not good if you want to help then edit that according my DATA I posted I have my own names which doesnt work with your answer sorry

Comment: @Jane1990 This answer demonstrates a technique. It is not meant as a full-blown solution. I can't modify the code you've shown in your question because there's not enough context. For example, we can't see the class or any function declarations which would help us to understand what you're trying to do. This is really basic. Your question refers to two different filenames so that's rather confusing too. If you're struggling then this may help: https://www.python.org/about/gettingstarted/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Regex method with this pattern `(.*)@.*:(.*)`
The parentheses means the text that fit in will be stored.

```
import re
m = re.search(yourText, '(.*)@.*:(.*)')
email = m.group(0)
passw = m.group(1)
```

Comment: unhashable type: 'list'